# Google drive API SCOPE : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Tags: scope, google-drive-api, editor, multi-tenant

I am making an multi-tenant platform that integrates client's Google drive to:

1. Create a folder in their Google Drive
2. Share Editor access with Tenants
3. Allow Tenants to create sub-folder and write documents.

I am using SCOPE: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  which works well.
However, the SCOPE is quite pervasive and Grant Full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files.

I just wanted access to create a folder editor access to things within.I don't want access to anything that client previously had in their Drive.

Do you think any way to have a limited SCOPE API?

Comment: In that case, how about using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`? The official document of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` says `Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.`. Is this the direction you expect?

Comment: Thanks! this worked. It gave me lot of errors I tried earlier  before your message. Sometime a second affirmation creates magic.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: SIde note: I would start the verification process early on this application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Tanaike! SCOPE: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file is what solved my problem.

> In that case, how about using the scope of
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file instead of
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive? The official document of
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file says Per-file access to
> files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a
> per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.. Is
> this the direction you expect? – Tanaike 58 mins ago